# Java OCR for images with complicated backgrounds

Tags: java, ocr, tess4j

I'm trying to get some text from images which look like this:
[image: img OCR example]

This example would actually be the best case scenario as most of them would have a colored and more complex background instead.
I don't need it to be 100% accurate since I know the possible outcomes and could try to do a partial match with them.

I tried Aspose OCR and Tess4j. Aspose gives me random characters and Tess4j gives nothing.

Is this doable with a free library?

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract seems to be the best free library for this purpose.

I know some projects using Tesseract do pre-processing to images they are OCR'ing. Like changing contrast, rotating, resolution, etc. Then they OCR same image with multiple times for different pre-processing changes and then compare the results.

More information [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ImproveQuality)